# storing data for a listView until user deletes it via android?

Tags: android, database, listview

i'm creating a time management app, that the user can set a startTime and endTime and a todo via a DialogFragment, which will then be sent to the activity to store in a ListView. the thing is though, i need the entries to be saved until the user deleted them. so what options do i have. i'd rather not do anything to technical or time-consuming. is there possibly an easy workaround for this aside from a DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few storage options in Android, outlined [in the docs](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html), but unfortunately the one you probably want is going to be a SQLite database. The absolute simplest storage option uses [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref), but that is only really useful for storing simple key-value pairs like the user's name, preferred location, etc.

Creating a database is not all that difficult or time-consuming, though. You just need to set up a simple table with string values for startTime, endTime, and todo. There's an easy-to-follow tutorial [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/).

The benefits of using SQLite to do what you're trying to do is that it allows you to store as many todos as your user wants easily, without trying to over-extend the SharedPreferences.

Comment: well from research it seemed those two and storing it to a file are my only options, so thanks for the advice i'll take your word for it and use a DataBase :)

Comment: Sorry I couldn't give you better news :) If this helped, marking the answer as accepted will help other users searching for similar questions.

Answer (score 0):

A database is always a good solution for persistent storage of data. An alternative could be SharedPreferences; it is a type of internal storage easily accessible from the Activity, where you can store elementary data types like integers or strings. In both cases, you cannot store the objects directly, but you will have to de-assemble them before saving annd re-assembling them at runtime.